# Is OpenStreetMap georeferenced?

Tags: geolocation, openstreetmap

I need to implement a GIS using an exported map from OpenStreetMap.
Is it georeferenced? In that case, is the precision enough to show GPS tracked devices over it without any additional georeferencing work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course it is. OSM is used in tons of [web services](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/List_of_OSM_based_Services), [routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing#End_users:_Routing_software), [mobile devices](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Software#Mobile_Devices), [desktop software](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Software#Desktop_software) and so on. A non-georeferenced map is pretty worthless, not only since recently.